# Triangular Numbers Pattern | FooBar

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop, while-loop

I m trying to create the below pattern using the below code

```
7
4 8
2 5 9
1 3 6 10
```

```
def createpattern(n=4,max_val=10):
    pattern = []
    for x in range(1,n+1):
        temp = []
        step = 2
        val = x
        bool_flag = 1
        while bool_flag == 1:
             temp += [val]
             if val == max_val:
                 print('----->')
                 bool_flag = 0
                 print('before break')
                 break
             else:
                val = val + step
                step += 1

        print('after break')
        print(temp)
        max_val = max_val - 1
        pattern.append(temp)
```

The break under while loop is working as expected

I m able to generate the first row however , the **range** in for loop is not moving to the next iteration value it is stuck at 1.

I have tried adding a continue at the end after append , however the loop is still stuck.

I m unable to figure out a way to rectify the above nested loop , ideally it should move to the next iteration value which I m unable to figure out why

Any leads would be helpful

Comment: Are `n` and `max_val` really independent, or should `max_val` always be the `n`th [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)?

Comment: not related to question: but you should use http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display . for debugging

Comment: @chepner , it was a naive attempt towards the pattern , hence opted for n and max_val to be independent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it, the approach that I was taking was very naive and had to research a bit on the patterns

Useful link for any pattern sequence formulae can be found here - [here](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C6%2C10&sort=&language=&go=Search)

Over the course the numbers in the required pattern tends to follow a trend and are a direct derivative of Triangular Numbers

Code Snippet --

```
def createpattern(x, y):
    pattern = []

    traingular_nums = [n*(n+1)/2 for n in range(1,y+x+1)]

    pattern.append(traingular_nums)

    for i in range(2,x+y+1):
        k = (i*(i-1)/2) + 1  <----- Formulae for Triangular Numbers
        temp = []
        temp.append(k)
        for z in range(1,len(pattern[i-2])-1):
            v = temp[z-1] + pattern[i-2][z+1] - pattern[i-2][z]
            temp.append(v)
        pattern.append(temp)
return pattern
```

The pattern was part of Google Foobar Challenge

Answer (score 1):

When calling the function with the default arguments and looking at it in a debugger, on the second iteration it produces `[2, 4, 7, 11, 16 ...` and goes on forever. Because none of these values is equal to max_val, `val == max_val` is never true. After changing it to `if val >= max_val:`, I get the following output:

```
----->
before break
after break
[1, 3, 6, 10]
----->
before break
after break
[2, 4, 7, 11]
----->
before break
after break
[3, 5, 8]
----->
before break
after break
[4, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop gets stuck due to the `if val == max_val` condition and incorrect step calculations. When the second row is created, the initial value of `step` should be 3, not 2. The result currently produced is `[2, 4, 7, 11, ...]` and the loop never terminates, since there is never a 9 in the array. That applies to the rest of the rows as well.